# Resize overlay video

Tags: ffmpeg

I am overlaying a video on top of an image.

Using this command:

`ffmpeg -i image.png -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=10:10:enable='between(t,0,38)'" -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy output.mp4`

I understand the `overlay=10:10` is the positioning but I can't seem to work out how to resize the overlay video (`input.mp4`).

I think I need to use `scale` but not sure how to.

Any help on scaling the overlay video would be appreciated!

Comment: improve your question by pasting the error / output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With filter_complex you can combine commands and make named outputs
Try something like this:
`ffmpeg -i image.png -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=320x240[scaled_v];[0:v][scaled_v] overlay=10:10:enable='between(t,0,38)'" -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy output.mp4`
Just change resolution to what you need instead of `320x240`.

If you need image overlay on top of video, swap `[1:v]` and `[0:v]`